# What is wrong in my webpack configurations?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I think i am doing everything right, but when i run `webpack serve` command, i get to a listing directory not the web page, may i be i am doing something wrong that make webpack can't find `index.html` file or may be something else:

**webpack.config.js file**:

```
const path = require('path');
const HTMLplugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HTMLplugin({
    template: './public/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html'
}) 

const rules = [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    }
];

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build')
    },
    module: {rules},
    plugins: [htmlWebpackPlugin]
}
```

**package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "hh",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode developent --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.3.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc.json** file:

```
{
   "presets" : ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react];
}
```

and this what i get when run `webpack serve`
[image]

What am i doing wrong in my configurations??..why i get that listing directory instead of my home page??

Comment: Have you tried setting the [contentBase](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devservercontentbase)?

Comment: @Christiaan it worked thank you, you can add your answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `webpack.config.js` is missing the [contentBase](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devservercontentbase) parameter.

This parameter will tell Webpack where to serve the content from. In your case, this is the `./public` directory:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
  }
};
```